# Rails / javascript trying to hide images that don't have a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to scrape images from a url, and only allow the user to pick images that are of a certain size.  I was having issues getting this to work good with Nokogirl, and thought about just proceessing it client side with jquery when the page to select the image's appears.   For some reason, it isn't working 100%

.select_product is the name of the image class that renders images for the user to select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").load(function () {
        $(".select_product").each(function () {
            var width = $(this).width();
            if (width < 100) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This js works, but for some reason it always see's the width on the "this" as having a width < 100, when in fact some images are certainly higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` event is fired once for every image, supposing you have 10 images, it's fired 10 times and when the first image is loaded the handler is executed even if other images are not loaded yet, you can listen to the `load` event of the `window` object instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".select_product").filter(function() {
       return $(this).width() < 100;
    }).hide();
}
```

But I would read the images' width on the server-side instead of loading and then hiding them, also note that jQuery `load()` event method as of jQuery 1.8 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the filter function.  Works great.. but yep, I need to really filter this server side.  After I applied this the pages loads all the images, then hides the elements after the page has loaded.. so a poor experience as you noted.   So that is another issue I have with nokogiri